# How to check if an existing table has a designated timestamp?

Tags: questdb

Once I have an existing table in QuestDB, is there any way to check if the table has a [designated timestamp](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/designated-timestamp/) and if yes, which column is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible as of version 6.0 using `tables()` and `table_columns()`. The following is an example which returns the schema of a table, including which column is set as a designated timestamp:

```sql
table_columns('my_table')
```

| column | type | indexed | indexBlockCapacity | symbolCached | symbolCapacity | designated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| symb | SYMBOL | true | 1048576 | false | 256 | false |
| price | DOUBLE | false | 0 | false | 0 | false |
| ts | TIMESTAMP | false | 0 | false | 0 | true |
| s | STRING | false | 0 | false | 0 | false |

For more information, see the documentation for [table meta functions](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/meta/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as of 5.0.6 I believe. This is definitely a missing feature.